# How to add Image to mahapps tabcontrol

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I want to create tab items with both text and image

I found [this](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/397) issue, but it's not relevant anymore, since `Controls:MetroImage` is outdated.

MetroDemo.exe has examples of how to use `TabControl`, but there's no demonstration on how to do what I'm trying to do.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MahApps simply extends or restyles the existing WPF controls.  What some people don't realize is that everything you want to do is already possible without doing anything special.

The [`TabItem.Header`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.headeredcontentcontrol.header(v=vs.110).aspx) property is an `object`, and is styled using a `ContentPresenter`.  What that means is you have the freedom to do something like this:

```
 <TabItem>
     <TabItem.Header>
         <Grid>
             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                 <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                 <ColumnDefinition/>
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <Image Height="20" Width="20" Source="Resources/myimg.png"/>
             <TextBlock Grid.Column="1">Hello World!</TextBlock>
         </Grid>
     </TabItem.Header>
 </TabItem>
```

Introduced in the MahApps pre-release (1.3.0+) is a new `ModernUIPackIcon` and variations, which greatly simplify using the pre-packaged icons that are currently in the MahApps.Resources package.  If you just want to use one of those, you can replace the `Image` element.

Comment: Hi, i have the same problem as the OP. This Solution omits the themed styles. So a Text only Header Property has this big blue/grey Text. You suggestion makes a little black Text(default Textbox style), with an Image. Is there a way to inherit the style from mahapps and still add an Image/custom Header stuff?

Comment: MahApps is designed to run in their window at the root.  If you don't you will have all sorts of issues like you are describing.

Comment: Fortunately i was lucky and found way to have both image and style: ```<TabItem >
                <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DockPanel>
                            <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="Bell" DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="Content or Binding or... Hello World!"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>                    
                </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>                
            </TabItem>```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am late but this is how I did and it works perfectly.

```
<TabItem  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="8">
            <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemContainerTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <icons:PackIconModern Width="16" Height="16" Kind="ColumnThree" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="12">Columns</TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ItemContainerTemplate>
            </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
        </TabItem>
```

And the output is -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the accepted answer "resets" the theme, i found a solution which preserves styles. This is done by using the ContentPresenter and a Headertemplate.

(DockPanel could be switched to a Grid.)

```
<TabItem >
    <TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                <iconPacks:PackIconMaterial Kind="Bell" DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/> <!-- or any other image -->
                <ContentPresenter Content="Content or Binding or... Hello World!"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>                    
    </TabItem.HeaderTemplate>
    <!-- normal Tab content-->              
</TabItem>
```